# Data does not update when i click on submit button

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

When i click on submit button it does not update data in database. I have looked 
many times to figure out what the problem is. I think problem is not with the code. It may be because of XAMPP. I'm using phpstorm and i have given database connection in both files. If you need additional information please let me know. Thanks

"This is supplier list file"

```
<table class="table-bordered table-striped table-highlight text-center">
                <tr class="bg-dark text-white">
                    <th>Sid</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $q = "SELECT * FROM supplier";
                    $result = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db));
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $row[0];?>"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $row[0];?>"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $row[0];?>"><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="action" class="btn-primary"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"> update </a></button>
                        <button id="danger" class="btn-danger"><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"> delete </a></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
```

"This is update file"
In update file in first php tag the data will be submitted upon clicking the save button and **it should update data in database which is not happening and it is the main problem.** In second php tag the code is actually fetching the data form database and is being displayed in texatbox.

```
<?php
    include ('../../../includes/connection.php');
    ob_start();
    if (isset($_POST['save'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $newName = $_POST['newname'];
        $newAddress = $_POST['newaddress'];
        $newContact = $_POST['newcontact'];

        $q = "UPDATE supplier SET name='$newName', address='$newAddress', contact='$newContact' WHERE sid='$id' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db));
        header('location:viewSupplierList.php');
    }
    ob_end_clean();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Update</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/menu.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/hover.css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>

<body>
    <form class="form" method="POST" action="update.php">
        <h3>Update Supplier Details</h3>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['id'])){
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $q = "SELECT * FROM supplier WHERE sid='$id'";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db));
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
            }
        ?>

        <label for="id">ID</label>
        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>" disabled>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="newname" value="<?php echo $row[1];?>" title="Enter at least 5 characters!" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{5,20}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Only alphabets are allowed!')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="newaddress" value="<?php echo $row[2];?>" title="Enter at least 10 characters!" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{10,100}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Only alphanumerics are allowed!')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
        <label for="contact">Contact</label>
        <input type="text" id="contact" name="newcontact" value="<?php echo $row[3];?>" title="Enter at least 12 number!" required pattern="[0-9-]{11,12}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Numbers with or without hyphen are allowed!')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">

        <input class="hvr-bubble-float-top" type="submit" name="save" value="save">
        <input class="hvr-bubble-float-top" type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel">
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/menu.js" ></script>
</html>
```

Supplier table schema

```
sid|    name     |      address      | contact
--------------------------------------------------
 1 | Supplier A  | street abc blah.. | 038157575714
 2 | Supplier B  | street abc blah.. | 038157575714
 3 | Jhon        | street abc blah.. | 038157575714
 4 | Smith       | street abc blah.. | 038157575714
 5 | Michael     | street abc blah.. | 038157575714
```

Comment: update.php file is already given in description. I have updated the description with schema too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is that you have disabled the ID input. When a filed is disabled, it's not posted. Your update query receives an empty ID and there for does not execute the save. What you should do is make the input hidden instead.

```
<label for="id">ID: <?php echo $row[0];?></label>
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>" style="display:none">
```

On a side not, You should really use the browser developper tools. When you send a POST/GET request, it's saved in the network tab. You can use that to see the submitted values in the request headers and there for, you would have seen that id is missing and that's why your query is not working ;-)

Comment: Its working. But i don't want the id to be editable. I  there a way to make it look like disabled. Thanks for helping.